# Cannot export default with Webpack 4 and Babel 7

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, webpack-4, babel-loader

Here is some functionality that used to work for me with Babel 6, but I'm having issues with Babel 7. I'm trying to export a (default) class as a library. Currently I get the following error when I try to import it.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './dist/datastore.js' does not
>   provide an export named 'default'

My configurations are nearly identical to my former configs, just updated with Babel 7.

Bits from Webpack:

```
output: {
  path: `${__dirname}/dist`,
  filename: `${moduleName}.js`,
  library: 'datastore',
  libraryExport: 'default',
  libraryTarget: 'umd',
  umdNamedDefine: true
},
```

Bits from my entrypoint:

```
import DataStore from './datastore';

export default DataStore;
```

Bits from .babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env", {
      "targets": {
        "node": "current"
      },
      "modules": false
    }]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"
  ]
}
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using babel 7 you need to load this package:

```
npm i --save-dev babel-plugin-add-module-exports
```

And then add in your babel configuration this plugin 'add-module-exports':

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        modules: false,
        targets: {
          browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'safari >= 7']
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  plugins: ['add-module-exports']
};
```

Comment: Really? According to the documentation of that plugin, it only affect commonjs modules, whereas I'm trying to export an pure es component.

Comment: But Babel 7 Upgrade doc specifically states that they've `Dropped use of add-module-exports plugin`...am I missing something?

Comment: That's referring to the babel libraries themselves, e.g., if you are exporting something from babel to build your own babel plugin.

Comment: This fixed my issue